# Android-13 : help with logcat analysis please

Tags: boot-loop, boot, logging, android-13

logcat does not reveal what might be holding back Android-13 boot, I am not an expert at this.

In terms of Software, we have a setup to build Android-12 succesfully for our specific lunch menu & device spec (arm64 based). For Android-13 we have used the same setup and pointed to the following source branches.

ANDROID_BRANCH=android-13.0.0_r18 KERNEL_BRANCH=common-android13-5.10-2022-12

Console trace ends up in a OnBootPhase_XXX loop continually incrementing with similar output repeating. Nothing obvious seem to stand out in the trace such as Fatal errors

```
01-17 12:43:14.120  2587  2587 I SystemServiceManager: Starting phase 500
01-17 12:43:14.122  2587  2587 D SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500
01-17 12:43:14.124  2587  2587 D SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.security.FileIntegrityService
01-17 12:43:14.125  2587  2587 V SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.security.FileIntegrityService took to complete: 0ms
01-17 12:43:14.127  2587  2587 D SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.pm.Installer
01-17 12:43:14.129  2587  2587 V SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.pm.Installer took to complete: 0ms
01-17 12:43:14.130  2587  2587 D SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.os.DeviceIdentifiersPolicyService
01-17 12:43:14.132  2587  2587 V SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.os.DeviceIdentifiersPolicyService took to complete: 0ms
01-17 12:43:14.134  2587  2587 D SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.uri.UriGrantsManagerService$Lifecycle
01-17 12:43:14.161  2587  2587 V SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.uri.UriGrantsManagerService$Lifecycle took to complete: 26ms
01-17 12:43:14.163  2587  2587 D SystemServerTiming: OnBootPhase_500_com.android.server.powerstats.PowerStatsService
01-17 12:43:14.172  2587  2587 E StatsPullAtomCallbackImpl: Failed to start PowerStatsService statsd pullers
```

Eventually the following line in trace gives a hint that it has given up.

```
01-17 12:44:30.645  2160  2791 I keystore2: keystore2::watchdog: Watchdog thread idle -> terminating. Have a great day.
```

I realise this is limited information. I am new here and could not see a way to attach full logcat output.

How do we identify in logcat, the fatal event that prevents progress of boot process.

Any hints/suggestions on debugging this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Many thanks @Firelord I have uploaded it here https://gist.github.com/CJ144/625369040e3317cc1bae06f593fe4049

Comment: Any feedback would be much appreciated. Anyone who can help unblock this also have the potential to do an unofficial training session on android bringup debug techniques, paid of course.